# Embedding string to an icon and alerting on click

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app

I'm getting the phone number from parse.com database.I am appending them into a list and all.But i have to use an icon and when I click that icon,I have to alert the phone number or dial that number using the default phone app.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer

```
 <a href="tel:// + phone + "> <img id="contact" src="">
```

Similiarly,we can use sms:for launching message service with particular body too!